# Ruby on Rails request in background

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parallel-processing, resque, rails-activejob

In my Ruby on Rails app, a user can grant me permission to tweet on their behalf, so they can send prefilled tweets from the application. This is the flow:

- request to my server
- server request to twitter server
- based on the response of twitter, my users gets a response.

The request to twitter blocks my app. I use ActiveJob with resque for other communication with 3rd party applications and e-mail, but in this case I want to give the user response based on the twitter server response.

Is it possible to somehow do?:

- request to my server
- server request to twitter server
- put this in wait so my server can serve other requests
- get notified on twitter server response and send response to my user

It is not a problem that my user sending the tweet has to wait. I just do not want other users to wait on that.

Comment: Are you using Unicorn? http://unicorn.bogomips.org/, Passenger? https://github.com/phusion/passenger  or Puma? https://github.com/puma/puma

Comment: Have you tried running another request in a second window/tab whilst the first one is in this "waiting" state? You might just find that everything is working as you want it to already.

Comment: @ilanberci I use passenger with Nginx.

Comment: @Jon I was hoping on that. I changed the twitter url to a non existing (so blocked until timed out). In another browser the app did not respond until the time out occurred.

Answer (score 2):

One solution is to use ActiveJob and rescue to request from twitter and when twitter responds, you can use a realtime engine to respond back to the user.

Another solution is to use a server that supports multithreading (puma, rainbows!..).

I personally think that I would use a realtime service to solve this problem. Although it adds some overhead but on the long run it will help sustain a higher number of concurrent users.